# How can I display a model property name that is coming from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently am pulling a list of url's from a view using  Entity Framework 5 and MVC 5. I have the view populating all the links but I need each link to display their 'LinkState' names like in my model so it will output:

- Alabama
- Georgia
- etc.

with the link attached to the LinkState. Instead of the view foreach loop saying State Link. I cant get my model/controlled to pull the correct information.

**Repository:**

```
public class LinkRepository
{
    private readonly LinkLibrary _entities = new LinkLibrary ();


    public LinkRepository()
    {
        _entities = new LinkLibrary ();
    }


    public List<LinkModels> RetrieveStateLink(string year)
    {
        return
            _entities.vw_URLLibrary.Where(s => s.YEAR.Equals(year) && s.URL_TYPE.Equals("United States")).Select(m => new LinkModels()
            {
                UrlLink = m.LinkLocation
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class LinkModels
{
    public string LinkYear { get; set; }
    public string LinkState { get; set; }
    public string UrlLink { get; set; }
    public string LinkType { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListOfUrls{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetStateLinks()
    {
        var stateLink = new List<string>();
        var model = rr.RetrieveStateLinks("2014").Select(m=> m.UrlLink).ToList();
        foreach (var s in model)
        {
            stateLink.Add(s);
        }

        var rm = new LinkModels();
        rm.ListOfUrls = stateLink;

        return View(rm);
    }
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.StateLinkList)
        {
            <td>
                <a href="@item">State Link</a>
            </td>
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are returning a List of strings as opposed to a list of LinkModels. I updated the repository to return the url and link name

removed some unneccessary code in your controller and updated it to work with a list of LinkObjects. Then updated the view to display the info.

You will have to update your view `@model List<LinkModels>` instead of `@model List<string>`

```
public class LinkRepository
{
    private readonly LinkLibrary _entities = new LinkLibrary ();


    public LinkRepository()
    {
        _entities = new LinkLibrary ();
    }


    public List<LinkModels> RetrieveStateLink(string year)
    {
        return
            _entities.vw_URLLibrary.Where(s => s.YEAR.Equals(year) && s.URL_TYPE.Equals("United States")).Select(m => new LinkModels()
            {
                LinkState = m.LinkState,
                UrlLink = m.LinkLocation
            }).ToList();
    }
}

public ActionResult GetStateLinks()
    {
        var stateLink = new List<LinkModels>();
        var model = rr.RetrieveStateLinks("2014");

        return View(model);
    }

@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                <a href="@item.UrlLink">@item.LinkState</a>
            </td>
        }
```

Comment: when I do that nothing appears

Comment: There, now Model.LinkState should say "foo"

Comment: I got it that far but I need it to say the state name of the URL so each url is mapped to a state, so a url to a state page would need to say Georgia or Alabama instead of foo.

Comment: does vw_URLLibrary have a description column?

Comment: yes, the LinkState is the state name that corresponds to the link

Comment: since I am using @model List<LinkModels> is there anyway I can still do this? :

<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">'@'Html.LabelFor(model => model.LinkYear, new { '@'class = "control-label" })</a>

Comment: The right answer really depends on where it is in your code. I'd imagine thats above the foreach loop so you'd prolly want to do something like
<label>@Model.First().LinkYear</label>

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetStateLinks()
{
    var model = rr.RetrieveStateLinks("2014");
    return View(model);
}
```

---

**View (change your view model to list of LinkModels)**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <td>
        <a href="@item.UrlLink">@item.LinkState</a>
    </td>
}
```

Comment: I received this error and the '@item.UrlLink' and '@item.LinkState' does not register

'string' does not contain a definition for 'UrlLink' and no extension method 'UrlLink' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @masta_coda: did you change your view model in your view?

Comment: what do you mean? where do I need to change to list of link models? Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: in top of the View, you will find `@model List<string>` or something like this, you will need to change to `@model List<LinkModels>`

Comment: @masta_coda: can you check `rr.RetrieveStateLinks("2014")` if it has value?